# Url Alias not working for domain paths

Tags: path-aliases, domain-access, subsites

Iam using [domain access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module in my website and having multiple domains in my website for example iam having domains

1. test.example.com (primary domain)
2. test1.example.com

when iam creating a sample content "Contact" and provided with the URL alias as 'contact' (assume node id as 143), Under domain access options i select "send to all affiliates". When i try to access the below url

> test.example.com/contact (its working fine)
> test1.example.com/contact (page not found)
>
> test.example.com/node/143
> test1.example.com/node/143
> both are working

Is it possible to have a same URL alias for all the domains. I used [domain path](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_path) module and its not working as my need.

Thanks.